# php regex remove everything except http urls

Tags: php, regex, url

How should look a code removing everything except full http url from string?
it's there only way regex? if so, may somebody could give me any example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will extract a single URL from string:

```
$string = 'some random text then url http://www.example.com/ and more text';

preg_match('!https?://[\w+&@#/%?=~|\!\:,.;-]*[\w+&@#/%=~|-]!', $string, $match);

echo $match[0];
```

Will extract multiple URLs from string into an array:

```
$string = 'put some text http://stackoverflow.com/something/something.php some random text then url http://www.example.com/ and more text';

preg_match_all('!https?://[\w+&@#/%?=~|\!\:,.;-]*[\w+&@#/%=~|-]!', $string, $match);

print_r($match[0]);
```

So to essentially 'remove' everything but the URL you would set the string to the matched value:

```
$string = $match[0];
```